# configure apache to make the url starting by http://

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, bind

Is there a special parameter in the Apache configuration or in a virtual host configuration to get the url starting by http:// ?
Without a specific configuration for my site when I enter the url http://www.this-example.com I am redirect to www.this-example.com, have an answer ? Or is this not a problem due to Apache but to dns (e.g. bind) ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Apache issue, or any redirect or anything DNS related.

This is simply the fact that most browsers will hide the http:// part from URL in address bar, while will show https or some other protocol, if it is used, if you select all in address bar and paste in any blank field you will see http://www.this-example.com/

In Firefox for example, this is defined by browser.urlbar.trimURLs preference.

1. Type “about:config “ in the address bar and press enter proceed by agreeing to the warning.
2. Double-click on browser.urlbar.trimURLs preference to turn its value to false, and double click again to enable it again.

[image]